# mysql command executescalar returns null in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, executescalar

Let's say I have a query result that looks as follows:

```
ID    NAME    Phone
----  ----    -----
1     John    123456
2     John    125678
3     John    345678
4     Abby    456789
5     Abby    567890
```

I want to return just a single row instance of name: John, where the phone number like '12%'.

In c#, I wrote this syntax to get the PersonName variable as the result of the query.

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=" + "localhost" + ";" + "DATABASE=" + "testdb" + ";" + "UID=" + "root" + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + "" + ";");
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();    

    connection.Open();
    string selectQuery = "SELECT NAME FROM testtable WHERE Phone LIKE '12%' ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1";
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = selectQuery;
    string PersonName = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
    connection.Close();
```

I don't know whats wrong with my code but the PersonName returns null. What did I do wrong?

Comment: When you run the selectQuery against the db directly (not via the code you show) what are the results?

Comment: Is the Phone column type a text or number column?

Comment: it returns 1 column 1 row with the value John.

Comment: Also: don't forget to use try/finally or using blocks to wrap your connection object, or you could end up locking yourself out of the database.

Comment: its a number column. when I run the query against the db directly it returns John, like I was expected. I did insert table query with the similar order of command initiation. I couldn't find the error of my code.

Comment: If you're getting a scalar value back when running the query directly, the error must be elsewhere.  Can you add additional code to your question showing where you instantiate connection and command?

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail @rfa, just a quick question and then I have one last thing to try.  Are your database and table both named testtable?

Comment: the db name is testdb and the table name is testtable. thanks

Answer (score 1):

We have to be missing something else here.  Try the following code sample based on what you provided:

```
try {
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=testdb;UID=root;PASSWORD=;");
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();    

connection.Open();
string selectQuery = "SELECT NAME FROM testtable WHERE Phone LIKE '12%' ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1";
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = selectQuery;
string PersonName = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally {
    connection.Close();
}
```

I have a feeling that for some reason the call to .Open() is failing and the error is being swallowed elsewhere.  Try the above and let me know what you find out.

Answer (score 0):

do this : change this `(string)command.ExecuteScalar();` by  `Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar());`

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=" + "localhost" + ";" + "DATABASE=" + "testdb" + ";" + "UID=" + "root" + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + "" + ";");
```

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();

```
connection.Open();
string selectQuery = "SELECT NAME FROM testtable WHERE Phone LIKE '12%' ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1";
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = selectQuery;
string PersonName = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar());
connection.Close();
```